# How do I use gdata and save a file on QPython for android?

Tags: android, sl4a, qpython, android-scripting

I am in the process of migrating my scripts from python SL4A to QPython (can't get SL4A to work on android lollipop).

**I can't save a file to the disk**
So I am using:

```
with open("foo.txt" ,"a") as f:
    f.write(theInfo)
```

And I get

```
IOError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'foo.txt'
```

I know what the error means, I just don't know where to save the file...

Thanks for the help,
marbs

Answer (score 3):

The error is saying that you are in a protected part of a file system.
That means you may want to save the file in an un-protected part.
So, you may want to replace the "foo.txt" part with "/mnt/sdcard/foo.txt" or "/storage/sdcard0/foo.txt" or whatever is the path of internal storage on your phone.
Do you understand what am I saying?

Answer (score 0):

Qpython has disabled writing to files, my recommendation is to find a different script interpreter like the inpython app on android, or the python module in Termux and run it from there.

Comment: I understand file writing has been possible since qpython 1.0 (and certainly is now with a correctly specified path), so this comment is no longer justified.